# Could Gambit rescue Rogue from Toad without injuring her?

Tags: marvel, x-men, toads-spit

If Rogue (Before gaining Ms. Marvel's powers) was slimed by Toad, and Gambit found her with the slime hardened to her face, would he be able to use his powers to charge the slime with kinetic energy and break it without causing Rogue harm?

Comment: This is the second time you've posted a "what would happen if X fought Y" question; the first one I rewrote for you to better fit with the community's guidelines, but this one you're on your own. Do you *really* just want to know if Gambit could save Rogue from Toad, or are you really asking about some *aspect* of Gambit/Rogue/Toad powers and this is just the only example you have?

Comment: Also, stop using the [tag:wolverine-and-the-xmen] tag incorrectly please.

Comment: Yes, Michael, I really would like to know if Gambit could save Rogue. As for the misuse of the wolverine and x-men tag, I am sincerely sorry; I am new to these types of sites and hope you understand as a fellow Marvelite

Comment: I feel like you'd be happier on Writing:SE. These questions aren't off-topic but they are going to attract downvotes

Answer (score 4):

As [Marvel Universe](http://marvel.com/universe/Rogue) explains, Rogue's near-invulnerability is a power she gained from Ms. Marvel.

> After permanently absorbing the powers of Ms. Marvel, Rogue possessed an amalgamated mutant human/alien Kree physiology that granted her a degree of immunity to poisons, and a virtually indestructible body.

As such, without Ms. Marvel's powers, an explosion to her face would harm her (assuming she has not temporarily absorbed anyone else's defensive or healing powers).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as Gambit was smart about it. For example, if he made skin contact with her FIRST (hands, neck, etc.), he would transfer his immunity to his own powers. However, no skin contact, no more Rogue.